# Bad Kibana performance, but good ElasticSearch performance

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana

We have been running ElasticSearch v. 1.6.0 and Kibana v. 4.1.0 with NGINX as proxy in production for about two months now and the set-up handles logging of multiple applications. We have 830.000 documents, total of 450MB and a single node. All log statements get shipped to ElasticSearch using Serilog, which creates an index per day.

When I run a query like

`curl.exe -XGET '[hostname]:9200/serilog-2016.02.20/_search
?q=*&sort=@timestamp:desc&size=500'`

then I get the results back in no time.

However, if I query Kibana just for the last 15 minutes, then NGINX returns a Bad Gateway after the request has waited for 2 minutes (each time TTFB passes 2 minutes) indicating that a timeout occurred.

The Kibana request is

`POST http://[hostname]/elasticsearch/_msearch?timeout=0&ignore_unavailable=true&preference=1455968700774`

with request payload

```
{
    "index": "serilog-2016.02.20",
    "ignore_unavailable": true
}{
    "size": 500,
    "sort": [{
        "@timestamp": {
            "order": "desc",
            "unmapped_type": "date"
        }
    }],
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": ["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],
        "post_tags": ["@/kibana-highlighted-field@"],
        "fields": {
            "*": {

            }
        },
        "fragment_size": 2147483647
    },
    "aggs": {
        "2": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "interval": "30s",
                "pre_zone": "+01:00",
                "pre_zone_adjust_large_interval": true,
                "min_doc_count": 0,
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "min": 1455967802350,
                    "max": 1455968702350
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {

                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": 1455967802352,
                                "lte": 1455968702352
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    "must_not": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": ["*",
    "_source"],
    "script_fields": {

    },
    "fielddata_fields": ["fields.effectiveDate",
    "fields.assignIpPortRequestModel.NeededFrom",
    "fields.ipPorts.LastCancelled.State.DateTime",
    "fields.returnedOrganizations.DateCreated",
    "fields.provisionings.CreatedAt",
    "fields.ProductParameterData.StartDate",
    "fields.provisioningEvent.UpdatedAt",
    "fields.networkConfig.Expiration",
    "fields.returnedOrganizations.DateModified",
    "fields.provisioningEvent.CreatedAt",
    "fields.ipPorts.State.ActiveFrom.DateTime",
    "fields.ptpPorts.LastCancelled.State.DateTime",
    "fields.portReservationData.ExpirationDate",
    "fields.productInstanceDtoList.StartDate",
    "@timestamp",
    "fields.ipPorts.State.LastCancelled.DateTime",
    "fields.productInstanceWithProductDtos.StartDate",
    "fields.neededFrom",
    "fields.portNeededFrom.State.DateTime",
    "fields.products.StartDate",
    "fields.productList.StartDate",
    "fields.networkReservation.Expiration",
    "fields.portReservationData.Products.StartDate"]
}
```

I've spent the last week trying to figure out what was causing the bad performance. I modified our index pattern in Kibana from serilog-* to [serilog-]YYYY.MM.DD (not default in v. 4.1.0), but that hasn't helped.